# Get outside parentheses in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

All right, this is stupid, but I have no clue how people deal with this and I'm hoping I'm missing something...

When I write something like this:

```
if (n == 0)
```

...The closing parenthesis gets added as soon as I type the opening one. The only way *I* know of to get out of them now is to reach over and tap the End key or something, which kind of ... Damages my shui, you know? And yet apparently they thought this feature was a cool idea, so...

What do you normally do to tell the IDE that you're done with this bit and you're ready to move on to the next? Same question applies to automatic quotes and stuff in the XAML editor, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just keep typing - if you type your own `)` when the cursor is just before the automatic one, it should not create another `)`, but just move the cursor over it.

(Disclaimer: I'm not certain this works on a vanilla Visual Studio - I have a bunch of extensions installed)

Comment: I am waaaaay too OCD to have ever figured that out on my own. Thank you so much! (Yes, it works in vanilla VS.)

Answer (score 6):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a new line below the current one without moving the cursor to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

To add to this, Tab is another option and I find it easier:

- In your example, type the logic, press Tab to skip passed the end bracket.
- If you are inside auto quotes, type your text, then press Tab twice.

Like the other answer, it only applies when first being typed, so if you go back to edit something, you are left using the End and Arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015 with Productivity Power Tools installed (probably works earlier as well), when being inside an auto-complete block (quotes or braces):

<kbd>end</kbd> goes to line end ( typically slow to type/find)

<kbd>"</kbd>/<kbd>)</kbd> typing same key as auto-complete already inserted will simply replace the auto-inserted character

<kbd>tab</kbd> jumps over end of auto-complete (e. g. braces or quotes)

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> adds ; at end of line, goes to new line (often what you want)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> goes to new line

Answer (score 0):

There is a short key in VS - "Edit.LineEnd" - pressing "End" you get to the end of the current line. I've re-assigned it (for me the best variant was "Alt-Enter") and use it to get outside of parentheses and quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Hit the enter key when you are done typing.

Comment: Hitting the enter key only goes to a new line while being inside the parenthesis or curly braces